# How to find out that instance is from Class c and not subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

`instanceof` shows if an instance is from class C or a subclass of C.

Is there a way to make sure that an instance is **not** a subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case use `getClass()` and compare it with the desired class:

```
boolean sameClass = someObject.getClass() == YourTargetClass.class;
```